# Extracting 'a' tags containing specific substring with Python's BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, tags, beautifulsoup, recompile

Using BeautifulSoup, I would like to return only "a" tags containing "Company" and not "Sector" in their href string. Is there a way to use regex inside of re.compile() to return only Companies and not Sectors?

Code:

`soup = soup.findAll('tr')[5].findAll('a')
print(soup)`

Output

```
[<a class="example" href="../ref/index.htm">Example</a>,  
<a href="?Company=FB">Facebook</a>,  
<a href="?Company=XOM">Exxon</a>,  
<a href="?Sector=5">Technology</a>,  
<a href="?Sector=3">Oil & Gas</a>]
```

Using this method:

`import re
soup.findAll('a', re.compile("Company"))`

Returns:

`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'`

But I would like it to return (without the Sectors):

`[<a href="?Company=FB">Facebook</a>,

<a href="?Company=XOM">Exxon</a>]`

Using:

- Urllib.request version: 3.5
- BeautifulSoup version: 4.4.1
- Pandas version: 0.17.1
- Python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `soup = soup.findAll('tr')[5].findAll('a')` and then `soup.findAll('a', re.compile("Company"))` writes over the original soup variable. `findAll` returns a ResultSet that is basically an array of BeautifulSoup objects. Try using the following to get all of the "Company" links instead.

```
links = soup.findAll('tr')[5].findAll('a', href=re.compile("Company"))
```

To get the text contained in these tags:

```
companies = [link.text for link in links]
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! Is there a simple value extraction method--e.g., `soup.findAll('tr')[5].findAll('a', href=re.compile("Company")).value()` to get `["Facebook", "Exxon"]`?

Comment: Yeah there is. I edited my post with that additional information. You could do it all in one step by replacing `links` within the generator statement although I wouldn't recommend it for the sake of readability.

Comment: And do you have a similarly easy way to get the href values--e.g., `companyHref = [link.get for link in links]`?

Comment: One way to keep the two values linked would be to use dict comprehension. Same concept as above, but now the result is a dictionary where the keys are the company names and the corresponding values are the href attributes `companies = {link.text: link.href for link in links}`. Didn't test this, BTW.

Comment: Wyatt: So this should return the names of each href?

Comment: No it creates a dictionary associating these two values. The dictionary is of the form `d={"Facebook":"?Company=FB", "Exxon": "?Company=XOM"}` where you can access the href using `d["Facebook"]` or iterate through them with `d.items()`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is xpath, which supports AND/NOT operations for querying by attributes in an XML document. Unfortunately, BeautifulSoup doesn't handle xpath itself, but lxml can:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

r = requests.get("YourUrl")
tree = fromstring(r.text)
#get elements with company in the URL but excludes ones with Sector
a_tags = tree.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'?Company') and not(contains(@href, 'Sector'))]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *css selector* getting all the a tags where the href starts with `?Company`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

a = soup.select("a[href^=?Company]")
```

If you want them just from the sixth tr you can use *nth-of-type*:

```
 .select("tr:nth-of-type(6) a[href^=?Company]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the above answers @Padriac Cunningham and @Wyatt I !! This is a less elegant solution I came up with:

```
import re
for i in range(1, len(soup)):
    if re.search("Company" , str(soup[i])):
        print(soup[i])
```